# Functions published as a VS2015 Web Application not showing up in the portal list

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I followed the roadmap to create a set of Azure Functions as a Web Application.  They deployed without an issue to my Azure Function App.

I moved the project to a new solution and changed the name spaces and updated the function.json files.  When I redeployed to the Function App I was getting a bad entry point on one function which I double checked and tried to update a couple of ways without any success.

Thinking that the Function App might be caching I tried restarting the app and then finally went into the App Service Editor and deleted all the files and republished.  Now none of the functions show up in the list even through the directories and function.json files for each function are confirmed present.

Has anyone else experienced something like this or have a suggestion as to how to resolve it?

Comment: Your host logs will show details about the functions that have been detected and possible failures when initializing them. If you can share your folder structure, that would help identify a possible set of issues. Sharing your function app name (or an execution id) would also allow us to look at logs for your specific app.

Comment: I looked at the log files in home\LogFiles\Application\Functions\Host and didn't see anything that stood out.  I did see the earlier error before I deleted the contents and republished.  The Function App name is ULIO-POC-Fa-NCUS-AN.  Let me know if that is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your script file in `function.json` is set to a dll that doesn't exist in `bin`. Double check the dll name there.

You can see the content of `bin` folder on azure through debug console by going to `https://<yourAppName>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`

Comment: Thanks.  I had the old project dll name instead of the new one.  Look at something too long and you miss the obvious.